# How to use return in express error handling

Tags: node.js, express, error-handling, middleware

Is there a difference in an express application between these 2 pieces of code that calls an error handler?

```
return next(err); 
next(err); return;
```

Are they different or same and if different which one is correct/preferred?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`next` doesn't return anything, so these two statements are identical.
But the first one is shorter.